# Rest Endpoint with Springt Boot 3.0.0 not working anymore

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

Recently, I updated my dependencies of my Spring Boot Project to 3.0.0 and my rest end points stopped working.

My pom.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.app</groupId>
<artifactId>applicationdata</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.214</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>clean package jboss-as:run</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/applicationdata-database</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

My Resource looks likte that:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/test")
public class TestResource {

    @GetMapping(value="/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("success");
    }
}
```

Using Spring Boot 2.6.4 the rest end point works. Using Spring Boot 3.0.0 I get a 404 but no errors in the console. What am I missing?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Spring Boot 3 uses JakartaEE, you have some old crappy Tomcat 7 maven plugin which isn't JakartaEE. So it won't start and hence a 404. You need to deploy to Tomcat10.

Comment: However, my tomcat manager says that the application is deployed and running

Comment: Which is wrong without tomcat10 it simply won't work, regardless of what your tomcat is telling you.

Comment: You are right. I tried it with the a Tomcat 10. It works. Do you want to add it as an answer? Then, I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot 3 requires a JakartaEE Servlet container. That means, for Tomcat, that needs to be at least version 10.x, anything lower is still JavaEE.